# TypeError: Return value of PayPal\Braintree\Gateway\Config\PayPal\Config::getProductPageBtnEnabled() must be of the type bool

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.2

Getting this error after upgrading to Magento 2.4.2 on PDP pages.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be caused by a value for path `payment/braintree_paypal/button_productpage_enabled`  missing from `core_config_data` and the value not being converted to a bool.

This can be fixed by [this patch](https://github.com/zero1limited/magento2-patches/blob/master/patches/PayPal_ModuleBraintreeCore_getProductPageBtnEnabled_return_value_wrong.patch)

If you have [cweagans/composer-patches](https://packagist.org/packages/cweagans/composer-patches) installed you can add the following to your `composer.json`

```json
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "paypal/module-braintree-core": {
            "getProductPageBtnEnabled return value wrong": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zero1limited/magento2-patches/master/patches/PayPal_ModuleBraintreeCore_getProductPageBtnEnabled_return_value_wrong.patch"
        }
    }
},
```

Then just run: `composer install --no-dev`